# How to change elasticsearch max result windows from settings inside ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, error-handling, configuration

I want to increase the size of elasticsearch max result windows from settings inside ruby on rails (something like configuration file), so that I can just add the max result window size configuration to the rails app, without having to call it from commands or use curl.

knowing that (based on a stackoverflow answer) ... I tried to create a new file called elasticsearch.yml, and add index_max_result_window = 15000, but this didn't work for latest versions of elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Use `index.max_result_window` [instead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html).